Who is Callie Spengler's mother in Ghostbusters: Afterlife?
Callie is the daughter of Egon Spengler first introduced in Ghostbusters: Afterlife.  From postcards and some other things seen in the 2021 film, we can tell she was two years old in 1984.
Who is her mother?
Why didn't Egon ever mention his daughter Callie or his ex-spouse in any of the first two films?
Did he ever try to have a family relationship with them?

Not confirmed. They just had him have a daughter and haven't really gone into any backstory
https://www.cinemablend.com/interviews/the-big-ghostbusters-afterlife-mystery-we-asked-about-callies-mom-and-got-weird-answers
